# Renaming files in subdirectories using a bash script in linux

Tags: bash

I am trying to rename all the files within the subdirectories in my folder. The file structure is as follows:

```
PQR/
    aaa.txt
    bbb.jpg
    ccc.jif
XYZ/
    aaa.txt
    bbb.jpg
    ccc.jif 
LMN/
    aaa.txt
    bbb.jpg
    ccc.jif
```

What I want:

```
PQR/
    PQR_aaa.txt
    PQR_bbb.jpg
    PQR_ccc.jif
XYZ/
    XYZ_aaa.txt
    XYZ_bbb.jpg
    XYZ_ccc.jif 
LMN/
    LMN_aaa.txt
    LMN_bbb.jpg
    LMN_ccc.jif
```

I am trying to use the following bash script but its giving me all kinds of errors (I am relatively new to shell scripting so bear with me).

```
#!/bin/bash/
for dirname in */
do
 cd $dirname
 dirnew=${dirname/\///}  #To escape the forward slash
 for file in *.*          #Reading the files in the directory
 do
   mv "$file" "$dirnew"_"$file"
 done
 cd ..
done
```

Comment: To check your script for common problems you can use http://www.shellcheck.net/# and http://explainshell.com/

Comment: Thanks! did that and made changes as necessary. Still getting a "Bad substitution error though. Am I escaping the forward slash incorrectly here?

Comment: I echoed the "dirnew" variable and it doesn't show me the forward slash as being replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dirnew = ${dirname/\///}
```

A variable assignment cannot have whitespace around the equals sign, and the lefthand side should not have a `$`. Also you've got one too many slashes in the substitution.

```
dirnew=${dirname/\//}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still getting an error though. It says:
           `rename_files.sh: 6: rename_files.sh: Bad substitution`

Comment: My bad. Thanks a lot!